# firebase messaging not working in android after updated compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 30 to 31

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I updated compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from 30 to 31 and I didn’t get any notifications I'm using
`"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.12.0"`

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this issue, this is because Notification trampoline restrictions:

To improve app performance and UX, apps that target Android 12 or higher can't start activities from services or broadcast receivers that are used as notification trampolines. In other words, after the user taps on a notification, or an action button within the notification, your app cannot call startActivity() inside of a service or broadcast receiver.

I solved this by updating code as follows:
In react-native we are using:`react-native-firebase v5.5.6`

Go to DisplayNotificationTask.java in :

> node_modules/react-native-firebase/android/src/main/java/io/invertase/firebase/notifications/DisplayNotificationTask.java

Find PendingIntent.getActivity

```
 return PendingIntent.getActivity(
  context,
  notificationId.hashCode(),
  intent,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

replace the code with following code

```
int flags = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE :  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId.hashCode(), intent, flags);
```

Find PendingIntent.getBroadcast

```
return PendingIntent.getActivity(
  context,
  notificationId.hashCode(),
  intent,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
```

replace the code with following code

```
int flags = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE : PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId.hashCode(), intent, flags);
```

Update AndroidManifest.xml `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` :

Add `android:exported="false"` in all service contain name like "firebase"

In `android/app/build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {

    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0" 
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:20.2.0" 
}
```

In in `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
       }
    ...
}
```